# How come django with 1 thread can serve concurrent access?

Tags: django, multithreading, concurrency

I have some doubt in my mind, currently I confused to determine concurrent access of the server. Let say I am not using uwsgi/gunicorn for my django application, it means I am running application with 1 thread and 1 worker right ? , so it means that we just can open 1 connection in a time, which means that it is impossible to create concurrent access right ? , so how come that default django can serve concurrent access ?

Comment: What do you mean by concurrent access though? Requests shouldn't take much time to serve, so a single thread can serve many requests consecutively.

Answer (score 9):

You only say how you're *not* running the application, not how you are.

But if you use the development server (`python manage.py runserver`), it is multithreaded.

If you want to run it without threading, use the `--nothreading` option.